# Using pivot_longer to restructure wide data, with multiple columns, from a spreadsheet

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have attempted several solutions using several R functions including reshape, gather, and pivot_longer. My problem is that the data comes from a spreadsheet that has multiple columns. I will attempt to represent a sample of the spreadsheet:

| FullName | SOCW725 | SOCW748 | SOCW799 | Average | SOCW725 | SOCW752 | SOCW782 | Average | SOCW725 | SOCW748 | SOCW752 | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Beavis B | 3.5 | 3.22 | 2.56 | 3.07 | 2.33 | 3.33 | 4.2 | 3.5 | 3.33 | 3.23 | No Data | 3.00 |
| El Guapo | 3.25 | 3.02 | 2.75 | 3.18 | 3.33 | 4.33 | 4.15 | 2.25 | 2.67 | 3.42 | 4 | 2.44 |

The actual data file is much wider. Each set of three courses (e.g., SOCW725, SOCW748, SOCW799) represents a competency and there are nine competencies. I left those off the table as I believe I can insert those into a dataframe once I figure this out (I hope). So, I am trying to pivot_longer into three columns (will be 4 when the CompetencyID is added). The columns are: Name, Course, and Rating. I do not need the average as I can recalculate that. Following is an example of the code I am using:

```
d1 <- pivot_longer(my_data, 
               cols = !1, 
               names_to = "Course",
               values_to = "Ratings",
               )
```

This works, but the repeating rownames (i.e., Course names) have a . followed by a number (e.g., SOCW725.1, SOCW725.2, etc.). I understand why, but I don't know how to get rid of it. I can probably figure out how to edit the .#'s out of the result, but wanted to find a faster way with dplyr::pivot_table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are interested in returning the 'FullName' and the 'SOCW' columns (duplicated) in single column, `select` the columns of interest, then use `pivot_longer` with `names_pattern` as the `".value"` and capture the substring from the column name without the `.` (`[^.]+`) followed by digits.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
my_data %>% 
    select(FullName, starts_with("SOCW")) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("SOCW"), names_to = ".value", 
         names_pattern = '^(SOCW[^.]+)')
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  FullName SOCW725 SOCW748 SOCW799 SOCW752 SOCW782
  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Beavis B    3.5     3.22    2.56    3.33    4.2 
2 Beavis B    2.33    3.23   NA      NA      NA   
3 Beavis B    3.33   NA      NA      NA      NA   
4 El Guapo    3.25    3.02    2.75    4.33    4.15
5 El Guapo    3.33    3.42   NA       4      NA   
6 El Guapo    2.67   NA      NA      NA      NA
```

`data.frame` doesn't by default allow duplicate column names.  It uses `make.unique` to modify the column names by appending `.1`, `.2`, etc. for each duplicates.

---

if we need only three columns

```
library(stringr)
my_data %>% 
   select(FullName, starts_with("SOCW")) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("SOCW")) %>% 
   mutate(name = str_remove(name, "\\.\\d+$"))
# A tibble: 18 x 3
   FullName name    value
   <chr>    <chr>   <dbl>
 1 Beavis B SOCW725  3.5 
 2 Beavis B SOCW748  3.22
 3 Beavis B SOCW799  2.56
 4 Beavis B SOCW725  2.33
 5 Beavis B SOCW752  3.33
 6 Beavis B SOCW782  4.2 
 7 Beavis B SOCW725  3.33
 8 Beavis B SOCW748  3.23
 9 Beavis B SOCW752 NA   
10 El Guapo SOCW725  3.25
11 El Guapo SOCW748  3.02
12 El Guapo SOCW799  2.75
13 El Guapo SOCW725  3.33
14 El Guapo SOCW752  4.33
15 El Guapo SOCW782  4.15
16 El Guapo SOCW725  2.67
17 El Guapo SOCW748  3.42
18 El Guapo SOCW752  4
```

#### data

```
my_data <- structure(list(FullName = c("Beavis B", "El Guapo"), SOCW725 = c(3.5, 
3.25), SOCW748 = c(3.22, 3.02), SOCW799 = c(2.56, 2.75), Average = c(3.07, 
3.18), SOCW725.1 = c(2.33, 3.33), SOCW752 = c(3.33, 4.33), SOCW782 = c(4.2, 
4.15), Average.1 = c(3.5, 2.25), SOCW725.2 = c(3.33, 2.67), SOCW748.1 = c(3.23, 
3.42), SOCW752.1 = c(NA, 4L), Average.2 = c(3, 2.44)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. This is close, but I still end up getting a separate column for each SOCW### value.

Comment: @AlanLipps I thought you want separate individual columns.  If you need a single column, it is more easy

Comment: @AlanLipps I updated the post with new output.  It is better to show the expected output in your post so that it is more easier to crosscheck

Comment: Thank you for the updated code. I will definitely remember to show the desired result next time. That works really nicely. I do have another related question. There is actually one more column I thought I would be able to figure out once I got this part solved. I will post the new question as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

With your help [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun), I was able to get it to work with this:

```
d1 <- pivot_longer(my_data, 
                    cols = !1, 
                    names_to = "Course",
                    values_to = "Ratings",
                    names_pattern = '^(SOCW[^.]+)'
                    )
```

Regular expressions are on my bucket list of things to learn.